# Given real $r_1, r_2 > 1$ with $r_1 \neq r_2$, choose large powers $r_1^m, r_2^n$ such that $\frac{r_1^m}{r_2^n}$ approaches $1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

### Context:

In the "Answers and hints for the exercises" section of Neal Koblitz's *p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions Second Edition*, this technique is invoked to aid in Chapter I §2 Exercise 5. We have a (non-trivial) norm $\left\Vert \:\: \right\Vert_1$ on a field $F$, as well as two elements $a,x \in F$ with $a \neq x$ and $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_1, \left\Vert x \right\Vert_1 > 1$. Some relevant contradiction is achieved by **"choos[ing] large powers $x^m$ and $a^n$ such that $\left\Vert \frac{x^m}{a^n} \right\Vert_1$ approaches $1$"**. Using norm rules we can rewrite this as $\frac{\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1^m}{\left\Vert a \right\Vert_1^n}$, and, by letting $r_1 = \left\Vert x \right\Vert_1$ and $r_2 = \left\Vert a \right\Vert_1$, we have the more general setup in the title (with at least one issue noted in *What I don't know* below).

### What I know:

The process of choosing large powers $r_1^m, r_2^n$ such that $\frac{r_1^m}{r_2^n}$ approaches $1$ is formalized by requiring a sequence $\{c_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ such that:

1. $\exists m, n \in \mathbb{N}, c_k = \frac{r_1^m}{r_2^n}$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots$
2. If $c_k$ and $c_{k+1}$ have representations $\frac{r_1^\mu}{r_2^\nu}$ and $\frac{r_1^{\mu'}}{r_2^{\nu'}}$, then $\mu' \geq \mu$ and $\nu' \geq \nu$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots$
3. $\lim_{k \to \infty} c_k = 1$.

I would like help finding a rigorous proof for the existence of such a $\{c_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$. From here my knowledge is more qualitative and tangential.

I've come up with a cute sequence with properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ which from inspection I'm pretty sure contains a subsequence with property $(3)$, call it $\{d_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$, defined by:
$$d_0 = 1$$
$$d_{k+1} = d_k \times r_1 \:\: \text{if} \:\: d_k<1$$
$$d_{k+1} = d_k \div   r_2 \:\: \text{if} \:\: d_k \geq 1$$
Each plot in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVVPG.png) shows the first 200 members of $\{d_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ for $r_1, r_2 = 2, \ldots, 11$, corresponding to rows and columns, respectively. Most charts off of the main diagonal have a sweeping behavior, hitting near any point between $\frac{1}{r_2}$ and $r_1$. If you extend these plots very far then the whole range is covered. This is why I claim that there is probably a subsequence of $\{d_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ with property $(3)$.

### What I don't know:

In the setup under *Context*, I'm not sure if the $r_1, r_2$ constructed actually have $r_1 \neq r_2$, since that is not directly implied by $a \neq x$. There might be some bit of setup from the book which clarifies this, or maybe I'm wrong. For that reason I'll include the full quote here:

> Suppose $\left\Vert \:\: \right\Vert_1 \sim \left\Vert \:\: \right\Vert_2$. Let $a \in F$ be any nonzero element with $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_2 \neq 1$, say $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_2 > 1$. Then there is a unique $\alpha$ such that $\left\Vert a \right\Vert_1 = \left\Vert a \right\Vert_2^\alpha$. *Claim*: $\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1 = \left\Vert x \right\Vert_2^\alpha$ for all $x \in F$. If, say, there were an $x$ with $\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1 > \left\Vert x \right\Vert_2^\alpha$ (also suppose $\left\Vert x \right\Vert_1 > 1$), then **choose large powers $x^m$ and $a^n$ such that $\left\Vert \frac{x^m}{a^n} \right\Vert_1$ approaches $1$**; but then show that $\left\Vert \frac{x^m}{a^n} \right\Vert_2$ approaches $0$, and hence the two norms are not equivalent. Finally, note that $\alpha > 0$, or else we would not have $\left\Vert \:\: \right\Vert_1 \sim \left\Vert \:\: \right\Vert_2$.

I'm unfamiliar with the tool of choosing large powers like this, so my question here (for myself and a broader audience) is ***more about that tool than the proof outline in which it's contained***.

#### Edit (import note):

Have you seen this technique used anywhere else?

Comment: Unsure if I am interpreting the problem correctly.  $(r_1)^m \approx (r_2)^n \implies m\log(r_1) \approx n\log(r_2)$.  If $\displaystyle \frac{\log(r_2)}{\log(r_1)}$ happens to be irrational, then you can routinely construct integer sequences $\langle m_k\rangle, \langle n_k\rangle$ such that $(m_1/n_1), (m_2/n_2), (m_3/n_3), \cdots$ approach $\displaystyle \frac{\log(r_2)}{\log(r_1)}$.  As I say, I am unsure whether I have interpreted your question as intended.

Comment: That’s very promising thank you! Now all that’s left is to formalize the details of the existence of such *non-decreasing* integer sequences, I think.

Comment: $(m_0=1, n_0=1)$; $(m_{k+1}=m_k+1, n_{k+1}=n_k)$ if $\frac{m_k}{n_k} \leq \frac{\log (r_2)}{\log (r_1)}$; $(m_{k+1}=m_k, n_{k+1}=n_k+1)$ if $\frac{m_k}{n_k} > \frac{\log (r_2)}{\log (r_1)}$ should work

Comment: While your approach might work, it seems counterintuitive.  I would choose another approach.  What I said about $\displaystyle F = \frac{\log(r_2)}{\log(r_1)}$ applies not only if $F$ is irrational, but also applies if $F$ is the rational quotient $\frac{P}{Q} ~: ~P,Q$ are coprime integers, and the prime factorization of $Q$ includes any prime number other than $2$ or $5$.  For example, I would express $\sqrt{2}$ by $\langle m_k\rangle = 1,14,141, \cdots,$ and $\langle n_k\rangle = 1, 10, 100, \cdots.$  ...see next comment.

Comment: A similar approach will work with (for example) $F = (1/7) = 0.\overline{142857}.$  For $F = (P/Q)$ rational, the alternate approach that I would choose is $\displaystyle m_k = \left[(10)^k P - 1\right]$ and $\displaystyle n_k = \left[(10)^k Q - 1\right].$

Comment: I hope you'll agree that if $m_k = \left \lfloor (k + 1) \frac{\log (r_2)}{\log (r_1)} \right \rfloor$ and $n_k = k + 1$ then $\{(m_{10^k-1}, n_{10^k-1})\}_{k=0}^\infty$ gives the same sequence from your $\sqrt{2}$ example. I've given $\{\frac{r_1^{m_k}}{r_2^{n_k}}\}_{k=0}^\infty$ the same treatment as $\{d_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ above (plotted the first 200 members of each sequence corresponding to $r_1, r_2 = 2, \ldots, 11$) and it seems to have trouble converging in the same way as $d_k$. I'm convinced that $m_k/n_k$ converges to the right value, but not so much that the ratio of powers does.

Comment: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFdVv.png) are those plots

Comment: If anyone else tries to plot $\{\frac{r_1^{m_k}}{r_2^{n_k}}\}_{k=0}^\infty$, I recommend applying $t \mapsto e^{\log (t)}$ and simplifying to $\exp \left [ \left \lfloor (k+1) \frac{\log (r_2)}{\log (r_1)} \right \rfloor \log (r_1) - (k+1) \log (r_2) \right]$, which is easier to compute.